# WPF Anti aliasing workaround

Tags: .net, wpf

Anti aliasing [cannot be turned off](http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/wpf/thread/1ad9a62a-d1a4-4ca2-a950-3b7bf5240de5) in WPF. But I want to remove the blurred look of WPF fonts when they are small.

One possibility would be to use a .net 2.0 component. This looks like it would lose the transparency capability and Blend support. Never tried it though.

Anyone has a solution for this? Any drawbacks from it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting a [WindowsFormsHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) control on a WPF window/control? That will allow WPF to render a WinForms control.

**UPDATE November 2012**: This question and answer is 4 years old. [Text rendering has since improved in WPF](https://web.archive.org/web/20160122031626/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx). Please don't put WinForms controls in WPF apps; that was a hackish way to fix font rendering. It's no longer needed.

Comment: This answer speaks volumes about the current state of WPF. Let's hope it improves in VS2010. ;)

Comment: Yes, it is, but this question is over 4 years old. Things have improved since then, particularly WPF font rendering: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Anti-Alias can be turned off starting WPF 4.0 with following option:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
```

Comment: That is actually not Anti-Aliasing turned off. It is a different, more clear version of the Anti-Aliasing setting.
The Aliased option is TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"

Answer (score 1):

SnapsToDevicePixels has absolutely no effect on text rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have a blog dedicated to text rendering in WPF here [WPF Text Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/)

Things have definitely improved in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Offset the objects you draw, that you don't want to be antialiased, by 0.5px. This will cause the drawing engine to draw *on* the actual pixels, rather than drawing *on the edge* of the pixels (which is the default). When drawing on the edge of a pixel antialiasing normally occurs on the surrounding pixels.

This is similar to Quarts drawing on Mac.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't read the question. This doesn't work for fonts, only for shapes. I will leave the comment here for reference, though.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the [UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) property on the UI elements of your window.  People tend to report it works best for [graphics and lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/seema/archive/2006/10/31/on-some-monitors-it-seems-that-thin-wpf-lines-are-blurred-across-two-pixels-instead-of-one-ick-how-do-i-get-sharply-rendered-lines.aspx), but I've noticed improvment in text rendering with it as well.

Comment: If done a direct comparison between two identical pieces of text and could not find any difference in the SnapsToDevicePixel setting. Also, judging from the technical reasons behind the "blurriness" I can't imagine how that could help.